# Restkit - didLoadObjects is receiving an empty array

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have read every post and went through the tutorials and I cannot figure out why the "objects" array is empty. In the didLoadResponse method I am able to see [response bodyAsString] in the log. Below is the xml I am loading and the code I am using for object mapping. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <articles> 
        <article> 
                <title>This is a test title for article 1</title> 
                <link>google</link> 
                <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  elit. Sed quis bibendum eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cum sociis  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus  mus.</description> 
                <publicationDate>23 Feb 2012</publicationDate> 
        </article>  </articles> 


RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]]; 
    [articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"]; 
    [articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"link" toAttribute:@"link"]; 
    [articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"description"]; 
    [articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"publicationDate" toAttribute:@"publicationDate"]; 

//I changed my BaseURL for this post 
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"myserverpath"]; 
    [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping forKeyPath:@"articles.article"]; 
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/restkit/restkit_test.xml" objectMapping:articleMapping delegate:self];
```

Comment: have you tested like this : [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping forKeyPath:@"articles"];

Comment: I have tried that and unfortunately it does not work. The strange thing is I can see the full xml in the log, so I know the data is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with ..

```
// RKLogLevelDebug or so..
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

..to see why the mapping could not be completed?

You could also try with rootKeyPath :

```
articleMapping.rootKeyPath = @"articles.article";
```